# Searching nearest geo objects by google places api

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

I need to write a small program which make searching of some category of objects (airports for example) near some geo point. But places API have the limit for the radius length of 50 000 meters. So it seems that using of longer radius has no any sense.

But I saw that when I simply opened google maps in browser and type 'airport' in the search input I'll got all the airports which google found in map region bounded by my browser window. If I want more airports I'll simply zoom out and receive results for bigger region. So it seems that google has some tools for this kind of searching.

So the question is - how can I do this kind of searching using google maps API, especially searching with the radius more than 50 000 meters?

Answer (score 0):

Let me know if you find proper solution. But I can think of a work around is to load all airports/category objects  and setCenter geo point and set zoom in good enough which can focus one or two near by airport/object from geo point you have.